# MongoDB aggregate $group $sum that matches date inside array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I'll explain my problem here and i'll put a tldr at the bottom summarizing the question.

We have a collection called apple_receipt, since we have some apple purchases in our application. That document has some fields that we will be using on this aggregation. Those are: `price`, `currency`, `startedAt` and `history`. `Price`, `currency` and `startedAt` are self-explanatory. `History` is a field that is an array of objects containing a `price` and `startedAt`. So, what we are trying to accomplish is a query that gets every document between a date of our choice, for example: 06-06-2020 through 10-10-2022 and get the total price combined of all those receipts that have a startedAt between that. We have a document like this:

```
{
    price: 12.9,
    currency: 'BRL',
    startedAt: 2022-08-10T16:23:42.000+00:00
    history: [
        {
            price: 12.9,
            startedAt: 2022-05-10T16:23:42.000+00:00
        },
        {
            price: 12.9,
            startedAt: 2022-06-10T16:23:42.000+00:00
        },
        {
            price: 12.9,
            startedAt: 2022-07-10T16:23:42.000+00:00
        }
    ]
}
```

*If we query between dates 06-06-2022 to 10-10-2022, we would have a return like this:* **totalPrice: 38,7**. 
*-total price of the 3 objects that have matched the date inside that value range-*

I have tried this so far:

```
AppleReceipt.aggregate([
        {
          $project: {
            price: 1,
            startedAt: 1,
            currency: 1,
            history: 1,
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$history",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          }     
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              { startedAt: {$gte: new Date(filters.begin), $lt: new Date(filters.end)} },
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            data: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
            totalAmountHelper: { $sum: '$history.price' }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$data"
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            totalAmount: { $add: ['$totalAmountHelper', '$data.price'] }
          }
        }
])
```

It does bring me the total value but I couldn't know how to take into consideration the date to make the match stage to only get the sum of the documents that are between that date.

**tl;dr**: Want to make a query that gets the total sum of the prices of all documents that have `startedAt` between the dates we choose. Needs to match the ones inside `history` field - which is an array of objects, and also the `startedAt` outside of the `history` field.

Comment: Rather than unwinding and regrouping, perhaps look into using `$reduce` (inside of an `$addFields` stage). You can use `$cond` to check the date and only add entries from the `history` array which have a relevant `startedAt` value

Comment: Thank you so much! There's so many things I still don't know about. Never saw $reduce before.  Definitely better than unwinding and regrouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/lOvRbX24QI9

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "history_total": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$history",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            $sum: [
              {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $gte: [
                          new Date("2022-06-06"),
                          {
                            $dateFromString: {
                              dateString: "$$this.startedAt"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $lt: [
                          {
                            $dateFromString: {
                              dateString: "$$this.startedAt"
                            }
                          },
                          new Date("2022-10-10")
                        ]
                      },
                      
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "$$this.price",
                  "else": 0
                }
              },
              "$$value",
              
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "history_total": {
        "$sum": [
          "$price",
          "$history_total"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "currency": "BRL",
    "history": [
      {
        "price": 12.9,
        "startedAt": "2022-05-10T16:23:42.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "price": 12.9,
        "startedAt": "2022-06-10T16:23:42.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "price": 12.9,
        "startedAt": "2022-07-10T16:23:42.000+00:00"
      }
    ],
    "history_total": 325.79999999999995,
    "price": 312.9,
    "startedAt": "2022-08-10T16:23:42.000+00:00"
  }
]
```

Kudos goes to @user20042973

Comment: Worked perfectly! I just did a few tweaks to match my filters, like substituting the things inside the ```$and``` to: ```{startedAt: { $gte: [new Date(filters.begin), "$$this.startedAt"] } },  { startedAt: { $lt: ["$$this.startedAt", new Date(filters.end)] } }```.
By the way, if I were to take into consideration the ```currency```, how would you go about doing it? Would you just convert after the total or as you go?

Comment: Depends :) If you have the different currencies in history this is a little bit tricky. Otherwise, I would append a calc step (add "JOIN" table) as a last stage.

Comment: Thank you! Will try it! Since you've been so helpful, how would I go about grouping them by year and month? So that the output would be something like this:
```[{  "_id": { "year": 2022, "month": 5 }, "totalPrice": 12.9 },
{  "_id": { "year": 2022, "month": 6 }, "totalPrice": 12.9 }]```
I put _id because that's probably a $group stage. I get really confused when there's an array, that's why initially I tried to unwind

Comment: Hope you asked for this one https://mongoplayground.net/p/AZuAf0N5yTh :)

Comment: Awesome but I think I didn't make it clear. I was thinking more like the expected result in that example you sent should also have month 5 and month 6. It's like the history is "separated" from the rest and each has a value and startedAt date. I did accomplish it by making two different querries, one for just the history and the other for the base document and after that, I made a reduce function that combines both values, so it is veery inefficient